# Create small high-quality GIF/APNG from a bunch of PNGs

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation, gif, png

I have 50 PNGs (like [those ones here](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh/raw/gh-pages/examples/pngs.zip)) and I would like to create a GIF (or APNG) animation from it that approximately retains the quality and is small.

What I'm doing so far is to rescale and throw `optipng` at them:

```
for file in step*.png; do \
  convert -trim -resize 200x200 $$file png8:$$file; \
  optipng -quiet $$file; \
done
```

After this, the size of the individual PNGs is about 30KB. (Perhaps more can be tuned here.) Then it's conversion time:

```
$ apngasm out.png step*.png
```

The output file, however, still clocks in at a whopping 1.3 MB.

[image]

Any idea of how to improve this?

Comment: What about dropping the number of colors to 2? `-colorspace gray -colors 2` or something. At 400x400; 2 color the size is about 6.4kb.

Comment: Have you investigated if apngasm somehow undoes the optimizations?